# Dynamically created graphical checkboxes are not found in panel.controls list

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am creating dynamic graphical checkboxes based on my database values inside a panel. but when i try to change the checked state while clicking on the select All checkbox. Nothing happens. I cannot find any controls inside that.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="EeekSoft.Web.Controls" Namespace="EeekSoft.Web.Controls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>                                 <div style="overflow: auto; height: 462px; width: 386px; margin-top: 0px;">
      <asp:Panel ID="optionPanel" runat="server" Height="479px" Width="380px">
      <cc1:GraphicalCheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" CheckedImg="images/checked.gif" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged"
      UncheckedImg="images/unchecked.gif" UncheckedOverImg="images/unchecked.gif" CheckedOverImg="images/checked.gif"
                                    UncheckedDisImg="images/unchecked_disabled.gif" Style="cursor: hand;" Font-Size="100%" AutoPostBack="true"/>
      <span class="survey_wizard_title" id="lblSelectAll" runat="server">Select All</span>
      </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack && Request["SurveyID"] != null)
    {
        surveyID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["SurveyID"]);
        PopulateParticipants();
    }
}private void PopulateParticipants()
{foreach (OptionPool opt in respOptions)
{
    Panel row = new Panel();
    GraphicalCheckBox cb = new GraphicalCheckBox();
    row.Attributes.Add("class", "surveyCheckbox");
    cb.ID = Convert.ToString(opt.id);
    cb.Attributes.Add("value", opt.id.ToString());
    cb.Text = opt.data;
    cb.Style.Add("cursor", "hand");
    cb.Font.Size = new FontUnit("100%");
    cb.UncheckedImg = "images/unchecked.gif";
    cb.UncheckedOverImg = "images/unchecked.gif";
    cb.CheckedImg = "images/checked.gif";
    cb.CheckedOverImg = "images/checked.gif";
    cb.UncheckedDisImg = "images/unchecked_disabled.gif";
    row.Controls.Add(cb);
    optionPanel.Controls.Add(row);
}}


protected void chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkSelectAll.Checked == true)
    {
        foreach (Control child in optionPanel.Controls)
        {
            if (!(child is GraphicalCheckBox))
                continue;

            if ((child is GraphicalCheckBox))
            {
                (child as GraphicalCheckBox).Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

optionPanel.control doesn't list any of the above dynamically created checkboxes.

Comment: project is ASP.NET or ASP.NET `MVC`?

Comment: It is a ASP.NET project. Not MVC

Comment: are you creating the dynamic controls in the page_init?

Comment: In page_load event. Like below.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateParticipants();
        }
    }

Comment: you need to create an recreate them in page_init.

Comment: It is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

To work with dynamic controls in ASP.NET beetwen postbaks, you need to recreate them in `Page_Init` method and with the same IDs each time

Comment: It is also not working.. Suggest me something else please